# Determine if a record update is performed via REST API?

Tags: rest-api

Our use case is to relax validation rules in cases where the update is made from an external system.

Each user authenticates individually so unfortunately we cannot look for an API user.

Comment: You'll need to create and propagate context to distinguish between user-coming-from-external system versus user-coming-from-wherever-else. Since wherever-else is very broad and undefined in your question, this becomes an open-ended question that is frowned upon around here. The answer in possible duplicate above is one potential option where "wherever-else" is a UI-based update.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how the other question relates to updates performed by the REST API?